# vb.net weird action with mouse button event and label

Tags: vb.net, button, label, mouse, isnumeric

I have a problem, `label1.text` need to reach number `5` with the `mouse left button` clicking on `label8` to make, a `tool strip menu item` appear, but even if is `5` it keep invisible except for clicking one time with the `mouse right button`. This is the code:

```
 Private Sub Label8_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label8.Click
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Label1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) + 1
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Label1.Text = 5) Then
                CustomizeModeToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to left click on label 8 to increase number? Your code says otherwise.

Comment: oh,sorry you're right, i just edited it, thanks for the correction.

Comment: `Label1.Text = 5` is a Boolean expression, not a number.  So using IsNumeric() does not make sense.  Put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file while you learn the language so the compiler can tell you about mistakes like these..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
Private Sub Label8_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label8.Click
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And  (Label1.Text <> "5") Then
                Label1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) + 1
            ElseIf  (Label1.Text = "5") Then
                    CustomizeModeToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            End If
    End Sub
```

Problem you had was to reach this:

```
Else
            If IsNumeric(Label1.Text = 5) Then
                CustomizeModeToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
```

You needed to right click since `if statement` took all left clicks. I didn't test it so if something doesn't work say it and i will fix it.

Comment: It give me a System.InvalidCastException on the first line after the sub of the label8, on the code line of the if e.button, with both mouse button case.

Comment: replace this IsNumeric(Label1.Text <> 5) with this (Label1.Text <> "5")

Comment: Yea, it works, but it's possible to make the tool strip menu item automatically appear after i reach the 5th click of label 8 ?

Comment: try CustomizeModeToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();

Comment: thanks a lot, now it's working on the 6th click, with only the left mouse button but it's ok anyways. Another question, how i can tell to the program to do nothing when it's right mouse clicked and doesn't show errors ?

Comment: That should be another question.  And you need to explain it better what you mean. You cane always capture with If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right and do what you want.

Comment: if it's showing on 6th click change 5's to 4's. And you can add above if statement  with MsgBox("Error Message Here") to let user know that right mouse click is not ok. Also Mark answer as correct since it helped you.